# Expected value of a random variable $X$ with density function $f(x) = \frac{5}{x^2}$ when $x > 5$

Tags: probability, integration, expectation

I am looking for $E[X]$ when $X$ has a density function $$f(x) = \frac{5}{x^2}$$

when $x > 5$ and $0$ elsewhere.

But $\int_5^\infty x \frac{5}{x^2}dx = 5\int_5^\infty x^{-1}dx = 5ln(x)\mid_5^\infty$

$=5[ln(\infty) - ln(5)]$

This seems to say that the expected value is $\infty$, which I figure means it's undefined. Have I made a mistake?

Comment: No mistake, the mean may be undefined. The use of "$\infty$" as if it were a number makes me uncomfortable, but the conclusion is correct, the integral diverges.

Answer (score 1):

The density $f(x)=\dfrac{\alpha x_m^\alpha}{x^{\alpha+1}}$ is of a [Pareto distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution).  In this case $\alpha =1$ and $x_m=5$.

A Pareto distribution has an infinite mean when $0 \lt \alpha \le 1$ as in this case, and an infinite variance when $1 \lt \alpha \le 2$.